# How to expand lists?

Tags: nlp

In lists the main noun is often only mentioned at the end. However, for e.g. NER-tasks, I would like to "expand" them:

- Outward and return flight -> outward flight and return flight
- Proboscis, Vervet, and golden snub-nosed monkey -> Proboscis monkey, Vervet monkey, and golden snub-nosed monkey
- education in mathematics or physics -> education in mathematics or education in physics

Are there already tools out there (bonus points for support of German language)? Google only led me to expanding contractions ("I've" -> "I have")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is related to syntactic analysis: one needs to obtain a [parse tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_grammar#Dependency_vs._phrase_structure) of the noun phrase, then it's possible to expand by mapping the head of the phrase with the different parts of the conjunction.

I think you can find dependency parsers for German, for instance in the [NLTK library](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.parse.html) or [Spacy](https://spacy.io/api/dependencyparser).

I don't know if you would find a library which provides precisely the expansion though, I would expect that there is a bit of programming to do from the parse tree.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll look into it! I'm a bit surprised that no library exists for this yet. Isn't such an expansion a common problem?

Comment: @gebbissimo As far as I know it's not that common, but as usual I don't know everything! The main application for this would be [relationship extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship_extraction) (see also [here](https://nlpprogress.com/english/relationship_extraction.html)). But it's a much more general and complex problem so I'm not sure it's relevant to your case.